# Change default properties of QRCode using iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, itext, qr-code

I have created a program which places QRCode on PDF. I have used iTextSharp for this purpose.
I am able to successfully generated QRCode but I am not able to change default options of Margin and Scale. Also please help me for changing or verifying Code Type.
Following is the code that I have written.

```
IDictionary<EncodeHintType, Object> hints= new Dictionary<EncodeHintType,object>();
hints.Add(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);
BarcodeQRCode QRCoode = new BarcodeQRCode(txt_bardata.Text.Trim(),1,1,hints);            
iTextSharp.text.Image imgQR = QRCoode.GetImage();
```

Comment: By "scale" do you mean "size", which is the `1,1` that you are using? iText will use either the size you specify or the minimum size required to make the QR code, whichever is larger. By "margin" are you talking about the whitespace around the QR code? Per spec, this is set at 4 times the width of a dark module. Many systems are fine with trimming this down but this constant is currently [baked into iText](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/qrcode/QRCodeWriter.cs#l29).

Comment: Chris, I got about size. But is there any way to set margin (White area around barcode).

Comment: If you look at the line I referenced above you'll see that `QUIET_ZONE_SIZE` is defined as a constant and it is used directly, not via a property that you can override. I think the only way that you are going to be able to change this is to download the source and compile your own DLL. You could also contact iText and see if they are willing add a feature allowing you to override this constant.